# getting error while inserting data in mysql using node and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I am just inserting data into a MySQL db using node and angularjs, I'm getting a 500 internal error while using express to route the specified URL for insertion purpose.

This is my node and angular code please correct me if there's anything wrong in the code.

Node Js (server.js)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());       
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 

var mysql = require("mysql");
var http = require("http");
var path = require("path");

/*
  * Configure MySQL parameters.
*/
var connection      =         mysql.createConnection({
        host        :         "localhost",
        user        :         "root",
        password    :         "",
        database     :         "two_way_demo"
});

connection.connect(function(error){
  if(error)
    {
      console.log("Problem with MySQL"+error);
    }
  else
    {
      console.log("Connected with Database");
    }
});

/*
  * Configure Express Server.
*/
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/angular"));
/*
  * Define routing of the application.
*/
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);    
    res.sendfile("index.html");
});
app.post("/addd",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    /* TODO: Now just check that your drive function is correct, SQL is correct and whether what arguements passed to SQL callback is correct */
    mysql.query('Insert into user_info (profile_picture,news) VALUES (""+req.body.pics+"",""+req.body.feed+"")',function(err, results, fields) {
        //if (err) throw err;
        if (err) {console.log("DB Error"); res.send("add failed");}
        else res.send("add success");
    });
    //res.send("success");
});
/*
  * Start the Express Web Server.
*/
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("It's Started on PORT 3000");
});

Angular js

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
#add_cont{
    margin-top: 118px;
    margin-left: 498px;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-app="two_way" ng-controller="two_way_control">
<form class="form-inline" id="add_cont">
<input type="text" name="feed" ng-model="news.feed" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter News"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="pics" ng-model="news.pics" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Image URL"><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" ng-click="submit(news)">
</form>
</div>
<script>
var app=angular.module("two_way",[]);
app.controller("two_way_control",function($scope,$http,$interval){
$scope.news={};
/* put $http into a service. Keep controllers thin */
$scope.submit = function(newpost){
    /* processData:false why do you need this? */
    /* I can see the code behind this $interval */
        console.log("triggering post");
        $http({method:"post", url:"http://localhost:3000/addd", data:newpost})
            .then(function(data){
                /* Success callback */
                console.log("success");
            },function(err){
                /* Failure callback */
                console.log("failed");
            });
    };
});
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your server-side code, you should using **connection.query** to replace **mysql.query**:

```
app.post("/addd",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    /* TODO: Now just check that your drive function is correct, SQL is correct and whether what arguements passed to SQL callback is correct */
    mysql.query('Insert into user_info (profile_picture,news) VALUES (""+req.body.pics+"",""+req.body.feed+"")',function(err, results, fields) {
        //if (err) throw err;
        if (err) {console.log("DB Error"); res.send("add failed");}
        else res.send("add success");
    });
    //res.send("success");
});
```

Comment: hi am getting this error in my server please help

 ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'req.body.pics' in 'field list'

Comment: Try to replace your code with **connection.query('INSERT INTO user_info SET ?', {profile_picture: req.body.pics,news:req.body.feed}, function(err, result) **, for safe and simple purpose.